# print('Hello World!') not using 'e' nor 'p' in the code with python

Tags: python, printing, built-in

This question might seem silly.
It's a simple useless task, but I believe it's a good way to learn things (I did learn a lot while doing this kind of tricks).

So, idea is in the title:
No 'e' allowed => no eval() or exec()
No 'p' allowed => no print() or import

What I tried is to get the print function from:

```
dir(__builtins__)[133]
```

but it's returned as a string, I found no way to get it as a callable function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a silly useless task.

Comment: You could use `inspect`, but that breaks your rules. Anyway, `inspect.getmembers(__builtins__)[133][1]('Hello World!')` would work.

Comment: If these are the types of questions you like, you may enjoy https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. Seems more suitable there.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, I voted to close. You were the one who said the question was silly and useless (and simple). In reality, writing complex obfuscated code is a good way to earn the ire of the [maintenance programmer](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-noble-art-of-maintenance-programming/) - if you want to print Hello World do so in the clearest most readable way you can. Deliberately deciding to skip the letters "e" and "p" on a whim is not the best way to do so.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok. Of course, I'm not planning to use this in a production code, but It's a good way to learn about __builtins__ . Abarnert's explanations are very useful to me, as they can be to other users I think. I don't see why 'real' problems should be the only acceptable entry points to learn elements of language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the order of the builtins dict is random, this is not a very useful thing to do, unless you're just as happy calling `staticmethod` as `print`.

But it may be worth knowing how to get from there to the next step you were trying to get to.

Modules are just objects, like any other objects. So, you can get their attributes with `getattr`. OK, so that's against your rules. But most objects—including modules—store their attributes in a dict. So:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)[133]
'staticmethod'
>>> __builtins__.__dict__[_]
<type 'staticmethod'>
```

---

Is there any way we could actually get `print`? Well, maybe not guaranteed, but pretty close:

```
>>> [v for k, v in __builtins__.__dict__.items() if 'rint' in k]
[('print', <function print>)]
```

Oops, I used an `e` for that `items`, right? Fine:

```
>>> [__builtins__.__dict__[k] for k in __builtins__.__dict__ if 'rint' in k]
[<function print>)]
>>> [__builtins__.__dict__[k] for k in __builtins__.__dict__ if 'rint' in k][0]('zzz')
zzz
```

---

But meanwhile, how were you planning to build the string `'Hello World!'` without an `e`? There are lots of options—`\x` or `\u` escapes, or something really silly like `rot13`. And all of those options would work to get you the string `'print'` just as easily. So, I'm not sure why you're trying to pull `print` out of the module's names in the first place.

```
>>> __builtins__.__dict__['\x70rint']
<function print>
```

---

As John Anderson pointed out in a comment, using the `inspect` module is nicer than going to the `__dict__`. For one thing, it works for objects that store attributes elsewhere—or even objects that generate them on the fly with a custom `__dir__` and `__getattr__`.

```
>>> [v for k, v in inspect.getmembers(__builtins__) if k == 'print'][0]
<function print>
```

The problem is, how do we get the `inspect` module? We can use the same backslash/etc. tricks to get the name `'inspect'` easily, but (unless we can assume it was already imported into `sys.modules`—and that `sys` is also already imported), we need to `import` or `__import__` or use `importlib` or… they've all got a `p` in them. And then, to get at `getmembers`, we need to go through the `inspect` module's dict to look it up by name.

But still, maybe it's better to do that once than every time:

```
>>> i = __builtins__.__dict__['__im\x70ort__']
>>> ins = i('ins\x70\x65ct')
>>> gm = ins.__dict__['g\x65tm\x65mb\x65rs']
>>> builty = lambda nam: dict(gm(__builtins__))[nam]
>>> builty('\x70rint')
<function print>
>>> builty('\x65val')
<function eval>
```

Of course using `lambda` to create a named function in a statement rather than an anonymous one in an expression is an anti-pattern, but then this whole post is a pile of anti-patterns. I'm doing it here to avoid the need for `def` and `return`, both of which have `e`s (as pointed out by Elliot Frisch). (It's hard to notice all the `e`s you type; even [Gadsby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsby_(novel)) had three accidental e's in it, and it's famous for being the novel with no e's…)

---

I'm sure someone is hoping that I'm going to show how to get around this by just using a compiled bytecode literal, right?

Unfortunately, there's only two ways to run a code object: either you wrap it up in a function object—which requires getting `FunctionType`, which requires either an `import` or a call to `type`—or you `exec` or `eval` it—which are already out.

Plus, in Python 3, all you'd be doing is cramming the constants `"print"` and `"Hello, World"` into `co_names` and `co_consts`, and then it's just a `LOAD_NAME`, `LOAD_CONST`, `CALL_FUNCTION`, `RETURN_VALUE` (which, coincidentally, happens to start with `e`: `b'e\x00d\x00\x83\x01S\x00'`).

In Python 2, on the other hand, `print` is a statement, and has a special `PRINT_ITEM` bytecode, so it's maybe a bit more fun:

```
>>> ty = builty('typ\x65')
>>> gattr = builty('g\x65tattr')
>>> f = lambda: None
>>> c = gattr(f, 'func_cod\x65')
>>> ct = ty(c)
>>> cc = ct(0, 0, 1, 0x43, 'd\x00\x00\x04GS', ('H\x65llo World!',),
...         (), (), '', 'h\x65llo', 0, '')
>>> xval = builty('\x65val')
>>> xval(cc)
Hello World!
'Hello World!'
```

(The extra quoted output at the end is because I just returned `"Hello World!"` because I was too lazy to dig up `None`. The code is `LOAD_CONST 0; DUP_TOP; PRINT_ITEM; RETURN_VALUE`.)

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sure, but the real fun is trying to import inspect without `p`…

Comment: Thanks a lot ! vars(__ builtins __)['\x70\x72\x69n\x74']('\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f \x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64') also works !

Comment: Sorry to be a spoil-sport, but "def builty(nam): return dict(gm(__builtins__))[nam]" has two "e"s. One in `def` and one in `return`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oops… OK, `lambda` has no `e` or `p`, so I can fix that.